# Angular having problem with .[i]?. brackes in html

Tags: angular

I have two applications, one is small and just has this one component for testing and the other is very large and complex and has the exact same component (same html and Typescript).  This code work good in the small app, but in the big one I'm getting this error when it builds from the component:

> Parser Error: Unexpected token [, expected identifier or keyword at
> column 30 in [VOForm.get('VORows')?.value?.[i]?.isEditable]

And this when it runs:

> Expected identifier for property access at the end of the expression
> [VOForm.get('VORows')?.value?.[i]?.isEditable]

This is occurring on the 5th line starting with *ngIf and references this:  .[i]?.

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="action">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Action </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; let i = index" [formGroup]="element">
        <button mat-icon-button class="material-icons app-toolbar-menu save-button"
            *ngIf="VOForm.get('VORows')?.value?.[i]?.isEditable" matTooltip="Edit" 
            color="primary" (click)="EditSVO(VOForm,i)">
            <mat-icon>edit</mat-icon>
        </button>
    </td>
</ng-container>
```

Both apps have the "exact" code in both the component.html and component.ts files.  In the small app the code above works perfect and the button is visible as expected.

To fix the error in the big app I removed the [] brackets like this: .i?.  and the full html below:

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="action">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Action </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; let i = index" [formGroup]="element">
        <button mat-icon-button class="material-icons app-toolbar-menu save-button"
            *ngIf="VOForm.get('VORows')?.value?.i?.isEditable" matTooltip="Edit" 
            color="primary" (click)="EditSVO(VOForm,i)">
            <mat-icon>edit</mat-icon>
        </button>
    </td>
</ng-container>
```

Now the page loads as expected and I don’t get any errors.  However, the button is not visible which means it's not able to read the "isEditable" property.

Note:  The html and Typescript in both apps for this component is exactly the same so there must be a conflict in the big app.  Below is the package.json file incase you can see something that would cause this problem.  Please advice on how to trouble shoot or fix this problem.  Thanks!

```
{
  "name": "goldstar",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start-client": "ng serve goldstar-client",
    "start-internal": "node --max_old_space_size=8048 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng serve goldstar-internal",
    "start-qa": "ng serve --configuration=qa",
    "build": "ng build",
    "build-dev-client": "node --max_old_space_size=8048 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --configuration developmentPush --output-hashing=all --source-map=true goldstar-client",
    "build-dev-internal": "node --max_old_space_size=8048 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --configuration developmentPush --output-hashing=all --source-map=true goldstar-internal",
    "build-prd-internal": "ng build --configuration developmentPush goldstar-internal",
    "build:ssr": "ng run GoldStar:server:dev",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test",
    "install-dependencies": "npm install --force"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-material-components/datetime-picker": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/animations": "~12.0.3",
    "@angular/cdk": "^12.0.4",
    "@angular/common": "~12.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "~12.0.3",
    "@angular/core": "~12.0.3",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^12.0.0-beta.34",
    "@angular/forms": "~12.0.3",
    "@angular/material": "^12.0.4",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^12.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~12.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~12.0.3",
    "@angular/router": "~12.0.3",
    "@azure/msal-angular": "^2.4.3",
    "@azure/msal-browser": "^2.31.0",
    "@fullcalendar/angular": "^5.11.0",
    "@fullcalendar/core": "^5.11.0",
    "@fullcalendar/daygrid": "^5.11.0",
    "@fullcalendar/interaction": "^5.11.0",
    "@fullcalendar/list": "^5.11.0",
    "@fullcalendar/timegrid": "^5.11.0",
    "@kolkov/angular-editor": "^1.2.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^10.0.0",
    "@ngrx/store": "^12.5.1",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^13.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^6.0.0",
    "@types/googlemaps": "^3.43.3",
    "@types/underscore": "^1.11.3",
    "angular-file": "^3.6.0",
    "angular-plotly.js": "^4.0.4",
    "bootstrap": "^5.0.2",
    "bootstrap-icons": "^1.7.2",
    "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
    "devextreme": "22.1.3",
    "devextreme-angular": "^22.1.3",
    "exceljs": "^4.3.0",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "golden-layout": "^2.5.0",
    "html-to-text": "^8.2.0",
    "iconv-lite": "^0.6.3",
    "ics": "^2.35.0",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "jspdf": "^2.4.0",
    "jspdf-autotable": "^3.5.20",
    "jszip": "^3.10.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "ng-dynamic-breadcrumb": "^6.0.0",
    "ngx-clipboard": "^14.0.2",
    "ngx-google-places-autocomplete": "^2.0.5",
    "ngx-mask": "^12.0.0",
    "ngx-mat-multi-sort": "^0.7.4",
    "ngx-material-timepicker": "^5.5.3",
    "ngx-moment": "^6.0.2",
    "ngx-plaid-link": "^1.0.4",
    "ngx-spinner": "^12.0.0",
    "ngx-toastr": "^14.2.2",
    "plotly.js-dist-min": "^2.16.5",
    "primeflex": "^3.1.3",
    "primeicons": "^4.1.0",
    "primeng": "^12.0.1",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "save": "^2.5.0",
    "tslib": "^2.1.0",
    "underscore": "^1.13.1",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.11.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~12.0.3",
    "@angular/cli": "^12.2.16",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~12.0.3",
    "@angular/localize": "^12.0.4",
    "@types/file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "@types/graphql": "^14.5.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.5.14",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.179",
    "@types/node": "^12.20.55",
    "@types/plotly.js-dist-min": "^2.3.1",
    "@types/uuid": "^8.3.1",
    "graphql": "^15.5.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.7.0",
    "karma": "^6.3.17",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "ng-packagr": "^12.0.0",
    "typescript": "~4.2.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: The template syntax doesn't support all of the same javascript/typescript syntax and I believe optional chaining support is limited. [v12 interpolation syntax](https://v12.angular.io/guide/interpolation#syntax) Current versions _may_ support it, I don't know myself, might want to consider upgrading. Or check the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @GreyBeardedGeek.  That kind of worked, but saddly after working all night I don't remember exactly what issue I had.

I eventuallhy came up with the code below that worked and hopefuly it will help someone else, however, I will uptick you post because I liked it and think that concept will be useful for other situations.

Here's what is now working for me:

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="action">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef style="width: 100px;"> Action </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; let i = index" [formGroup]="element" style="width: 100px;">
        <button mat-icon-button class="material-icons app-toolbar-menu save-button"
            *ngIf="VOForm.get('VORows')?.value[i]?.isEditable" matTooltip="Edit" color="primary"
            (click)="EditSVO(VOForm,i)">
            <mat-icon>edit</mat-icon>
        </button>
    </td>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: I'm glad that you got it working, but for the benefit of others, I have to say that I think that you missed my point entirely, which was to keep template expressions very simple, and move any complexity that they need into a component method.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly what is causing your issue, but I've seen similar problems before.

It's good to remember that interpolation in a component's template has typescript syntax, but is not, in fact really the full typescript that is available in the component, and things can get weird when your template expressions get complex like this.

The likely solution is to put all of that complexity into a component method, and then make a simple call to that method from the template.

In your case, the method would be something like:

```
isEsitable(i: number): boolean {
  return VOForm.get('VORows')?.value?.i?.isEditable;
}
```

and then your template expression would be:

```
*ngIf="isEsitable(i)"
```

An additional upside to this is that the method is now easily testable.

P.S. did you mean

```
VOForm.get('VORows')?.value?[i]?.isEditable
```